# iCal4j and newlines

Tags: java, ical4j

I'm trying to read a calendar feed from http://meetup.com/, but it seems that iCal4j is unable to deal with linebreaks in X-ORIGINAL-URL attributes: it fails on this line:

```
X-ORIGINAL-URL:http://www.meetup.com/chicagoscala/calendar/ical/The+Chicago
 -Area+Scala+Enthusiasts+(CASE)+Meetup+Group/
```

with this exception:

```
net.fortuna.ical4j.data.ParserException: Error at line 7: Illegal property [ -AREA+SCALA+ENTHUSIASTS+(CASE)+MEETUP+GROUP/]
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserImpl.parse(CalendarParserImpl.java:133)
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarBuilder.build(CalendarBuilder.java:174)
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarBuilder.build(CalendarBuilder.java:155)
```

I filed a bug for it, but I didn't get any response yet. Is this a known problem?

BTW, this is a snippet of a hexdump of that file:

```
00000060  4e 0a 58 2d 4f 52 49 47  49 4e 41 4c 2d 55 52 4c  |N.X-ORIGINAL-URL|
00000070  3a 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f  77 77 77 2e 6d 65 65 74  |:http://www.meet|
00000080  75 70 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 63  68 69 63 61 67 6f 73 63  |up.com/chicagosc|
00000090  61 6c 61 2f 63 61 6c 65  6e 64 61 72 2f 69 63 61  |ala/calendar/ica|
000000a0  6c 2f 54 68 65 2b 43 68  69 63 61 67 6f 0a 20 2d  |l/The+Chicago. -|
000000b0  41 72 65 61 2b 53 63 61  6c 61 2b 45 6e 74 68 75  |Area+Scala+Enthu|
000000c0  73 69 61 73 74 73 2b 28  43 41 53 45 29 2b 4d 65  |siasts+(CASE)+Me|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, passing in an UnfoldingReader yourself seems to do the trick. If you set the buffer size large enough, it will be able to restore the value correctly. Strange.

```
reader = new UnfoldingReader(new InputStreamReader(uri.toURL().openStream()), 3000);
return new CalendarBuilder().build(reader);
```

I also set ical4j.properties to this:

```
ical4j.unfolding.relaxed=true
```

Not sure if that made a huge difference, but at least it works.

Comment: Worked for me, but I set the propertie in my java code : CompatibilityHints.setHintEnabled(CompatibilityHints.KEY_RELAXED_UNFOLDING, true);